# rails not recognizing project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I can create a new project using rails and I can use stuff like

rails migration ...

and i (correctly) get a error because the sqlite gem is missing.

but when i try using rails migration ... with a project i checked out from github, it doesn't recognize that it is a rails project i get:

```
Usage:
  rails new APP_PATH [options]

Options:
  -d, [--database=DATABASE]   # Preconfigure for selected database (options: mysql/oracle/postgresql/sqlite3/frontbase/ibm_db)
                              # Default: sqlite3
  -O, [--skip-active-record]  # Skip Active Record files
      [--dev]                 # Setup the application with Gemfile pointing to your Rails checkout
  -J, [--skip-prototype]      # Skip Prototype files
  -T, [--skip-test-unit]      # Skip Test::Unit files
  -G, [--skip-git]            # Skip Git ignores and keeps
  -b, [--builder=BUILDER]     # Path to an application builder (can be a filesystem path or URL)
      [--edge]                # Setup the application with Gemfile pointing to Rails repository
  -m, [--template=TEMPLATE]   # Path to an application template (can be a filesystem path or URL)
  -r, [--ruby=PATH]           # Path to the Ruby binary of your choice
                              # Default: /usr/bin/ruby1.8
      [--skip-gemfile]        # Don't create a Gemfile
```

and it goes on. any ideas?

edit: it's probably an important detail that earlier my rails wasn't working *at all*. i had to `cp /usr/bin/ruby to /usr/bin/local/ruby`

Comment: May be because it was build in older/newer rails version than your rails version. Try to figure it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect the project from Github probably uses Rails 2.x and you probably have Rails 3.x.

Either that or perhaps you just forgot to "cd" into the folder after getting it from Github.

You mentioned that earlier your Rails wasn't working at all.  If that's the case and if you need to switch among different versions of Rails, a really nice thing to try is rvm. It's really popular: http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/

Comment: how do i change rails version? i know i have older rails, but it is default 3.0.5 or something. i know i have an older version cause my project is hosted using passenger for apache and it's version 2.x.x

Comment: @tipu: uninstall old one and install new one. to uninstall use: "gem uninstall rails" and install new one as: "gem insatll rails" You can specify version if you want. It will not damage your code if you use two different rails version on one machine. So feel free to install new/old version of rails without uninstalling current one.

Comment: viewing the gems showed i had 3.0.5 and 2.X.X. i wasn't sure how to change rails version cause by default rails -v shows 3.0.5, so i did gem uninstall rails and i selected 3.0.5 and it works now, thanks.